# Fading the text of a text input box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an input box `$myInput = $('<input/>').val('Some text')`.

I would like to fade away the text of the input box, but *not* the input box itself. Can I use jQuery for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myInput.animate({'color':'white'});
```

to fade it out. To fade it back

```
$myInput.animate({'color':'black'});
```

I assume you have white background on input

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the color animation plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) to color the text to the input's background color (most probably white).